# Flask and WTForms curious render issue

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I have a specific problem with reusing a render function to render a simple form (using WTForms (not Flask-WTForms)) in Flask. Below is a boiled down version of the code which reproduces the problem.

I have two routes called "/one/" and "/two/". Route one will render the form with `thefield` not being required. Route two, however, will pass a `required=True` parameter to the render function (which in turn passes it to the form constructor).

In the below example the `render()` function is of course extraneous as I could directly construct the `Form` class in the "one" and "two" routes, but in the actual code a lot more is happening in that `render()` function which I abstract out in that way.

The curious problem that now arises is that when I first visit `/one/` the field is not required (correct). Then I visit `/two/` and the field is required (also correct). But when I now visit route `/one/` again, the field suddenly becomes required as well. And now no matter how many times a flip-flop between `/one/` and `/two/` the field will be required in all cases.

Unless I restart the server in which case the first visit to `/one/` will show a correct, optional field again and the cycle repeats.

If I print the actual value of `self.required` inside of the form class's constructor I get the correct value if I jump between the routes. The HTML output, however, is incorrect.

I'm pretty sure it is something facepalm-ly obvious going on here, but I cannot seem to see the light...

The Python code:

```python
from wtforms import Form, TextField
from wtforms.validators import Optional, InputRequired
import flask

app = flask.Flask('app')

class TheForm(Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.required = kwargs.get('required')
      if self.required:
          self.thefield.validators.append(InputRequired())

  thefield = TextField('Fancy label',
                       validators=[Optional()])


def render(required=False):
  form = TheForm(required=required)

  return flask.render_template('template.html',
                               form=form)


@app.route('/one/')
def one():
    return render()


@app.route('/two/')
def two():
    return render(required=True)
```

The Jinj2 template:

```jinja2
{{form.thefield.label}}
{% if form.thefield.flags.required %}*{% endif %}
{{form.thefield()}}
```

Comment: There is exactly one instance of `thefield`, a class attribute of `TheForm`.  Its `validators` list contains one instance of `Optional()`, plus an instance of `InputRequired()` for every time `two()` has been executed during the current run of the program.  Giving each instance of `TheForm` its own `thefield` (create it in `__init__()`, in other words) seems like a possible solution - but I know nothing about Flask, so there may be some reason why it has to be a class attribute.

Comment: Damn ... you are right. So basically on every call the validator list of `thefield` keeps getting appended to. On 10 requests to `/two/` we would have  10 `InputRequired()` validators set. And here I was assuming, for some reason, that each instance of the class got its own separate attributes, but all I'm doing is appending to a property of an attribute that is simply shared among all instances. Yes ... I would call this a facepalm.